# what should be the correct sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following schema:

```
 employee(fname,lname,e_no,age,address,sex,slary,dept_number)

 dpartment(dept_name,dept_number,dept_location)

 project(pname,pnumber,plocation,dept_number)

 works_on(e_no,pnumber,hours)
```

i have to find the name of the projects where all the employees work more than 3 hours.There might be some cases where an employee works less then 3 hours but others does more than three hours.
I need the project name where all the employee works more than three hours. Can't figure out how to take that into consideration.

Please help me out ! thanks

Comment: Have you tried to JOIN tables?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rephrase your question it's *find the projects where no employee works less than three hours*, i.e. the minimum hours is greater than three:

```
SELECT p.pname
FROM project AS p
JOIN works_on AS w ON p.pnumber = w.pnumber
GROUP BY p.pname
HAVING MIN(hours) > 3
```

Or using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM project AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 ( SELECT *
   FROM works_on AS w
   WHERE p.pnumber = w.pnumber
     AND hours <= 3
 )
```

Caution, this is not exactly the same, as it will return projects without assigned employees.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.pname
FROM project AS p
JOIN works_on AS w ON p.pnumber = w.pnumber
GROUP BY p.pname
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN hours > 3 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: seems working ...can you explain the having clause please...haven't used much 'having' in my sql...infact i am quite new to this..some explanation would be nice

Comment: @AL-zami `COUNT(CASE WHEN hours > 3 THEN 1 END)` is called a *conditional aggregate*: It counts records having more than 3 hours. If this number is equal to `COUNT(*)` then *all* project records have more than 3 hours associated.